# Loading JSON1 extension with Flutter sqflite

Tags: sqlite, dart, flutter, sqlite-json1

In my Flutter app I'm using sqflite to talk to a local database. I need to peek into JSON data. The [JSON1 extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) would be ideal for this. However, I can't [load the extension](https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html) in a Flutter app to make it available in my queries since the documentation is for C, not Dart.

- Should I compile in different architectures for iOS and Android?
- Where should the compiled file(s) be placed? I assume it's not added as an asset.
- How to access/load the C extension in my Flutter/Dart code?

Suggestions for other well supported local databases (document databases or databases that support JSON queries) for Flutter are also welcome. I looked into Couchbase Lite, but the plugins ([Fluttercouch](https://github.com/oltrenuovefrontiere/fluttercouch), [couchbase-lite-flutter](https://github.com/hemeda3/couchbase-lite-flutter)) are still under development.

Comment: Many sqlite instances enable json1 by default instead of using it as a loadable extension... Have you checked to see if that's the case with your toolchain?

Comment: I'm getting 'no such function: json_extract', so I'm assuming the json1 extension is not enabled unfortunately.

Comment: With sqflite version 1.2.1, I'm able to load the json function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `sqflite` uses the OS-supplied version of SQLite, which may not have json1 enabled.

Instead, use `sqflite_ffi`, which would ship a copy of SQLite with your application. Any recent version would include json1  automatically.

The process is explained here: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite_common_ffi/doc/using_ffi_instead_of_sqflite.md

The gist is:

1. Add `sqflite_common_ffi` and `sqlite3_flutter_libs` dependencies (in addition to `sqflite`).
2. Call `sqfliteFfiInit()` before opening the database `sqflite` in your app.

An added advantage is that the ffi version also has much better performance.