# How to load the json1 extension with Flutter Sqflite plugin?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, sqflite

I've searched up and down trying to figure out how to load the SQLite json1 extension in Flutter with the Sqflite plugin version 2.0.0+3, but unsuccessful so far. I want to use json1 methods eg. json_object() and json_group_array() as described in this link: https://sqlite.org/json1.html#jobj. My Flutter version is 2.0.6. Sqlite version is 3.28.0.

Someone else mentioned that "With sqflite version 1.2.1, I'm able to load the json function." in this link: [Loading JSON1 extension with flutter sqflite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53351775/loading-json1-extension-with-flutter-sqflite) but I could not find any additional info.

Appreciate any input, thanks!

Comment: So, it's been about 2 years. Did you ever happen to get this figured out? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It does not directly answer your question, but I used the drift package to be able to make use of SQLite extensions with flutter https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/using-sql/extensions/